# PHP - Unexpected T_CONST

Tags: php

When I run my codes to my localhost, it is just doing fine, but when I put it on my "webhoster" (*000Webhost*, The Free Version). The error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONST in
>   /home/a5532550/public_html/login/db-const.php on line 7

just shows up. The server is using PHP version of *5.2.* *, Apache version of *2.2.19 (Unix)* and MySQL version of *5.1*

***DB-Const Codes***

```
<?php
    const DB_HOST = ------;
    const DB_USER = ------;
    const DB_PASS = ------;
    const DB_NAME = ------;
?>
```

Comment: You've edit the code, so I'm just guessing, but have you put quotes around the real values?

Comment: You need PHP 5.3 for the keyword const: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php

Comment: Yep, and I tried it without the quotes too

Comment: If you are running PHP < 5.3, you need to use this construct: `define('DB_HOST', 'VALUE_GOES_HERE');`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prior to PHP 5.3, Constants may only be defined using the `define()` function and for change log [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php)

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', 'XXXX');

?>
```

Refer [docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

Answer (score 3):

Use define instead

```
define("DB_HOST", "hostname");
```